# TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating dispatch)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to combine React Redux with React Native, and I encountered this strange error while debugging the program:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'dispatch((0, _LoginActions.loginAction)(inputFormProp))')
```

The error is triggered in a login function from a component immediately after I run the program, and I don't know why I have it.

Here is my component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TextInput, ActivityIndicator, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { getLogger, issueToText } from '../core/utils';
import styles from '../core/styles';
import { Card, Button, FormLabel, FormInput } from "react-native-elements";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { loginAction } from '../actions/LoginActions'

export class LoginComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this)
}

render() {
    const { error, isLoading } = this.props;

    const inputFormProp = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    };

    return (
        <View style={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
            <Card>
                <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                <FormInput value={inputFormProp.username} onChangeText={(text) => inputFormProp.username = text} />
                <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                <FormInput value={inputFormProp.password} onChangeText={(text) => inputFormProp.password = text} />

                <Button
                    buttonStyle={{ marginTop: 20 }}
                    backgroundColor="#03A9F4"
                    title="SIGN IN"
                    onPress={this.login(inputFormProp)}
                />
            </Card>
            <ActivityIndicator animating={this.props.isLoading} style={styles.activityIndicator} size="large" />
        </View>
    );
}


login(inputFormProp) {
    const { store } = this.props.screenProps.store;

    const { dispatch } = this.props

    dispatch(loginAction(inputFormProp))
        .then(() => {
            if (this.props.error === null && this.props.isLoading === false) {
                if (store.getState().auth.token) {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductList', { token: store.getState().auth.token });
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
        });
}


}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
const { error, isLoading } = state.auth

return {
    error,
    isLoading,
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginComponent)
```

and here is my app.js code:

```
const initialState = {
  auth: { isLoading: false, error: null },
};


const rootReducer = combineReducers({ product: productReducer, auth: authReducer 
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk, 
createLogger()));

export const MyNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: LoginComponent },
  ProductList: { screen: ProductList },
});



export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyNavigator screenProps={{ store: { store } }} />
    );
  }
};
```

From what I've already searched about the error, it seems that the cause is the connect() function in my component, but I don't know what is wrong with it.

Here is my directory structure:

[image]

Here is the LoginActions file:

```
import { loginService } from '../services/LoginService'

export function loginAction(data) {
    return dispatch => {
        loginService(data);
    }
}
```

Here is the LoginService file:

```
import { httpApiUrl } from '../core/api';
import { getLogger } from "../core/utils";
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
const log = getLogger('auth/service');


export const loginService = (user) => (dispatch) => {
dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_STARTED' });
return fetch(`${httpApiUrl}/api/userdata/verify`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
})
    .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            Alert.alert('ERROR', 'User or password is incorrect');
            dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_FAILED', data: 'User or password is incorrect' });
        }
        else return response;
    }).then((response) => response.json).then((response) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCEEDED', data: response.json });

    })
    .catch(error => {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_FAILED', data: error.message });
    });
};
```

Here is the output of this.props

```
21:10:48: Object {
21:10:48:   "navigation": Object {
21:10:48:     "dispatch": [Function anonymous],
21:10:48:     "goBack": [Function goBack],
21:10:48:     "navigate": [Function navigate],
21:10:48:     "setParams": [Function setParams],
21:10:48:     "state": Object {
21:10:48:       "key": "Init-id-1515093047465-0",
21:10:48:       "routeName": "Login",
21:10:48:     },
21:10:48:   },
21:10:48:   "screenProps": Object {
21:10:48:     "store": Object {
21:10:48:       "store": Object {
21:10:48:         "@@observable": [Function observable],
21:10:48:         "dispatch": [Function anonymous],
21:10:48:         "getState": [Function getState],
21:10:48:         "replaceReducer": [Function replaceReducer],
21:10:48:         "subscribe": [Function subscribe],
21:10:48:       },
21:10:48:     },
21:10:48:   },
21:10:48: }
```

Comment: Can you make sure LoginActions exports loginAction and you are correctly importing it

Comment: I checked. The folder is ok, the name is ok
Here is my action :::


export function loginAction(data) {
    return dispatch => {
        loginService(data);
    }
}

Comment: when you import loginAction, can you console.log(loginAction) to check if it is available

Comment: Done. It prints undefined.

Comment: And now you know the reason for the error, make sure the import file location is right wrt the current file

Comment: I checked and it is :/. I posted my directory structure in the main post.

Comment: In that case can you also share the loginActions file

Comment: Done. They are in the main post

Comment: it's a default export - it should be regular export in your case

Comment: Still not fixed. Exactly the same error :/. But loginAction isn't undefined anymore.

Comment: loginService is exported as default, and you are importing it as a named import

Comment: Fixed that too,but still, the same error with the dispatcher.

Comment: in that case you need to go into api and utils file as well and check for the exports

Comment: The exports there are of const, functions and classes, with no additional imports and no default one. The console.log(dispatch) gives me undefined. I also added the console log of this.props in the main post.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the prefixed `export` keyword before the class declaration

```
class LoginComponent extends Component { //<--- export was present here 
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this)
}

render() {
    const { error, isLoading } = this.props;

    const inputFormProp = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    };

    return (
        <View style={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
            <Card>
                <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                <FormInput value={inputFormProp.username} onChangeText={(text) => inputFormProp.username = text} />
                <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                <FormInput value={inputFormProp.password} onChangeText={(text) => inputFormProp.password = text} />

                <Button
                    buttonStyle={{ marginTop: 20 }}
                    backgroundColor="#03A9F4"
                    title="SIGN IN"
                    onPress={this.login(inputFormProp)}
                />
            </Card>
            <ActivityIndicator animating={this.props.isLoading} style={styles.activityIndicator} size="large" />
        </View>
    );
}


login(inputFormProp) {
    const { store } = this.props.screenProps.store;

    const { dispatch } = this.props

    dispatch(loginAction(inputFormProp))
        .then(() => {
            if (this.props.error === null && this.props.isLoading === false) {
                if (store.getState().auth.token) {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductList', { token: store.getState().auth.token });
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
        });
}


}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
const { error, isLoading } = state.auth

return {
    error,
    isLoading,
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginComponent)
```

Also make sure that You are importing the LoginComponent elsewhere as a default import

Comment: My God it worked :D. Thank you so much for your time :D.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like a messed up module import due to either babel settings or something else. You could set a breakpoint on a line the browser is complaining about and evaluate `_LoginActions.loginAction` in console. To make sure it is undefined.

Than find _LoginActions in scopes and the problem will be evident. If not, than please let us know what the corresponding scope looks like. `Scope` is a tab in chrome dev tools debugger Sources section

Comment: Unfortunately the app is developed in react native on a windows pc, so I am not running it in chrome, but with npm start, a qr code and Expo.

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with the workflow, but surely there should be some debugging capabilities? I think here the author is connection chrome dev tools to the app somehow https://www.gravitywell.co.uk/latest/rd/posts/react-native-debugger-expo-awesome/

It's just today I had a similar looking error, and it was that I imported a module like `import * as cns from...` instead of 'import cns from` (using typescript). And in debugger the actual import was undefined. However I can't see the reason for this problem in your case ...

Comment: Looks like loginAction is undefined for some reason.